# Add numbers with java function

Tags: java

Code that should add numbers from user is: if function is added in main function then it adds , what is significance of return cause !does add if there is no return but if you do not add System.out.print("Sum is :" + (C + D)); then return(C+D) !does adds

```
public class AddVariation
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
           AddNumbers();
}

private static int AddNumbers()
{
    Scanner Num = new Scanner(System.in);        

    System.out.print("Number C :");
    int C = Num.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Number D :");
    int D = Num.nextInt();   

    System.out.print("Sum is :" + (C + D));

    return (C+D);        
}
}
```

Comment: This code won't even _compile_.  Is this what you are actually running?

Comment: So what's your question? ;)

Comment: Your last edit (v3) seems to provide a solution, if this is not a problem anymore, please rollback to the previous version. Answers are there to proposed the solution. If the question isn't answered. Please add an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to get the input from users in the `AddNumbers` method, then you do not need pass them as parameters.

You can declare it this way:

```
private static int AddNumbers() {

    .... 
    int C = Num.nextInt();

    ....

    int D = Num.nextInt();

    ....
}
```

and call it in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddNumbers();
}
```

Comment: @jvm_code If this answer soleved your problem, maybe you can mark it :)

Comment: how do u do that

Answer (score 0):

change the function prototype to :

```
private static void  AddNumbers()
```

and dont return anything

Comment: ys could do that change function return types TY

Comment: but why did you unaccepted my answer after accepting it  i got +15 then then straightway -17 haha

Comment: if you just want to add and print you can call a void function for it or do that in main itself.

Comment: what if you want int as return, could you do private static int AddNumbers() and then return(C+ D), did that but it did not , does return prints on console

Comment: then you have to catch that int in like this `int sum= AddNumbers()`  in the main function then then print it in console.

Comment: cause i already accepted someone else's answer for initial , recently started using stack is that fine T

Comment: @jvm_code if my answers suits you more you can change it . give  it a tick mark if you liked it.

Comment: how about i ask another question and you answer it then could chec it